# Call static function of Generic Type from Generic Type in typescript

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a function in a service class that is passed a generic type extending my Bean class.  I want the function to call a static function in the Bean class to create an array of Beans.  My code in the playground compiles, however I get a runtime browser error of

```
Uncaught TypeError: ctor.constructor.fromEntryList is not a function
```

If I remove the `.constructor` I get the array of beans created, however there is a typescript error without `.constructor`.

I am lost at how to correctly typescript code this function.  Any help is much appreciated as I have unsuccessfully found a prior answer on SO.

Code:

```
// Base class that will be extended
class Bean {
    id: number;

    static fromEntryList<T1>(ctor: new (p: number) => T1, numbers: Array<number>): Array<T1> {

        let result: Array<T1> = [];
        for (let anumber of numbers) {
            result.push(new ctor(anumber));
        }
        return result;
    }


    constructor(p: number) {
        this.id = p;
    }
}

// Base service class that will be extended
class BeanService {


    constructor() { }

    get_entry_list<T extends Bean>(ctor: new (p: number) => T): T[] {
        let x: T[] = (<typeof Bean>ctor.constructor).fromEntryList(ctor, [1, 2, 3, 4]);
        return x;
    }
}

let service = new BeanService();
let beans: Bean[] = service.get_entry_list(Bean);
```

[code in playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%2F%2F%20Base%20class%20that%20will%20be%20extended%0D%0Aclass%20Bean%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20fromEntryList%3CT1%3E(ctor%3A%20new%20(p%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%20T1%2C%20numbers%3A%20Array%3Cnumber%3E)%3A%20Array%3CT1%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20result%3A%20Array%3CT1%3E%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20(let%20anumber%20of%20numbers)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20result.push(new%20ctor(anumber))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20result%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(p%3A%20number)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.id%20%3D%20p%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Base%20service%20class%20that%20will%20be%20extended%0D%0Aclass%20BeanService%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20get_entry_list%3CT%20extends%20Bean%3E(ctor%3A%20new%20(p%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%20T)%3A%20T%5B%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20x%3A%20T%5B%5D%20%3D%20(%3Ctypeof%20Bean%3Ector.constructor).fromEntryList(ctor%2C%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%2C%204%5D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20x%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20service%20%3D%20new%20BeanService()%3B%0D%0Alet%20beans%3A%20Bean%5B%5D%20%3D%20service.get_entry_list(Bean)%3B%0D%0A)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your param definition in `get_entry_list`, it only defines type of ctor but missing static method interface, so accessing it raises compiliation error while runtime can access those property correctly works.

You may able to define constructor interface,

```
interface XXX<T> {
  new(p: number): T;
  fromEntryList<U>(ctor: new (p: number) => U, numbers: Array<number>): Array<U>;
}
```

which is basically representation of `Bean` then use it for param's signature

```
get_entry_list<T extends Bean>(ctor: XXX<T>): Array<T>
```

allows ctor supplied in get_entry_list can access static method.

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%2F%2F%20Base%20class%20that%20will%20be%20extended%0D%0Aclass%20Bean%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20id%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20static%20fromEntryList%3CT1%3E(ctor%3A%20new%20(p%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%20T1%2C%20numbers%3A%20Array%3Cnumber%3E)%3A%20Array%3CT1%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20result%3A%20Array%3CT1%3E%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20(let%20anumber%20of%20numbers)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20result.push(new%20ctor(anumber))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20result%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20constructor(p%3A%20number)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20this.id%20%3D%20p%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20XXX%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20new(p%3A%20number)%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%20%20fromEntryList%3CU%3E(ctor%3A%20new%20(p%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%20U%2C%20numbers%3A%20Array%3Cnumber%3E)%3A%20Array%3CU%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Base%20service%20class%20that%20will%20be%20extended%0D%0Aclass%20BeanService%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20constructor()%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20get_entry_list%3CT%20extends%20Bean%3E(ctor%3A%20XXX%3CT%3E)%3A%20Array%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20x%3A%20T%5B%5D%20%3D%20ctor.fromEntryList(ctor%2C%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%2C%204%5D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20x%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20service%20%3D%20new%20BeanService()%3B%0D%0Alet%20beans%3A%20Bean%5B%5D%20%3D%20service.get_entry_list(Bean)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(beans)%3B)

Comment: generic param may need to be re-clarified between T, U, T1 - I haven't fully clarified those in my code snippet. Still cruxwise you can see point.